# What does resultRedirectFactory?

Tags: magento2, customer, redirect, factory, vendor

I found a code at /vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/Login.php

/** @var Redirect $resultRedirect */
$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

I want to know everything related to this object. which model or class it linked to and how does it work.
The flow of the code and more information i need to have in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This "resultRedirectFactory" used to create redirect from your controller to another url

If you want to redirect it to another controller then simply create resultRedirectFactory and set path

```
$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
$resultRedirect->setPath('sales/order/view') // syntax is frontname/controllerdirectory/controllerclass
return $resultRedirect;
```

At last just return and get redirect to the path you set